# Does uninstall all google-related android apps help to stop google from sucking too much cellular data bandwidth?

Tags: mobile-data

Many friends and I notice that google loves to suck cellular data bandwidth even though the following actions was taken:

1. Restrict Background data from data usage menu
2. Do not use live wallpaper
3. Disable backup in settings > backup & restore
4. Go airplane mode when not in use.

Also, doing some research, it was mention that one may need to use AFWall+ but you need to root the phone, which means you need to void your warranty.

So, does uninstall all google-related android apps help to stop google-related apps (e.g. Android OS) from sucking too much cellular data bandwidth?

If there is no ways to stop it, my friends and I will abandon android since it is wasting our money and time finding ways to stop it from sucking too much cellular data bandwidth.

Comment: Well, uninstalling Google's apps will surely reduce data usage, but you might not be able to uninstall *all* Google apps unless you're rooted, or use custom ROM clean from Google apps. Either way, you need to unlock the bootloader to do that, which will void the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do does not really concern Google Apps but system apps in general. These apps that are installed with the system but are of no use (other than sucking bandwidth and memory) are called **Bloatware**. It is not possible to remove system apps in most of the devices unless they are rooted.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Disabling the System App]

Just long press on the app or choose App Info for this option. Disabled Apps do not use Bandwidth or clog device memory.

For rooted users, others options are available with **Titanium Backup** being best of the options right now.

[image: IMG: Titanium Backup]

There are also many custom ROMs available which do not rely on Google services or install their bloatware. [XDA Developers](http://xda-developers.com) might be a good place to start looking. Rooting voids warranty.